# Convert JSON column in dataframe to simple array of values

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert the JSON in the bbox (bounding box) column into a simple array of values for a DL project in python in a Jupyter notebook.

The possible labels are the following categories: [glass, cardboard, trash, metal, paper].

```
[{"left":191,"top":70,"width":183,"height":311,"label":"glass"}]

TO

([191 70 183 311], 0)
```

I'm looking for help to convert the bbox column from the JSON object for a single CSV that contains all the image names and the related bboxes.

[image: FN and BBOX]

**UPDATE**

The current column is a series so I keep getting a "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Series'" any time I try to apply JSON operations on the column. So far I have tried to convert the column into JSON object and then pull out the values from the keys.

BB_CSV 
[image]

[image]

Comment: what is 0 for  ?

Comment: @W-B 0 is the number that represents the label. 1 would be cardboard, 2 would be trash so on and so forth

Comment: @cleme001, have you tried anything as of now in order to achieve it, that will also provide a clue what really is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a JSON decoder: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
import json
li = json.loads('''[{"left":191,"top":70,"width":183,"height":311,"label":"glass"}]''')
d = dictionary = li[0]
result = ([d[key] for key in "left top width height".split()], 0)
print(result)
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want map the operation of extracting the values from the dictionary to all element of the list, you can do:

```
extracted = []
for element in li:
    result = ([element[key] for key in "left top width height".split()], 0)
    extracted.append(result)

# print(extracted)
print(extracted[:10])
# `[:10]` is there to limit the number of item displayed to 10
```

Similarly, as per my comment, if you do not want commas between the extracted numbers in the list, you can use:

```
without_comma = []
for element, zero in extracted:
    result_string = "([{}], 0)".format(" ".join([str(value) for value in element]))
    without_comma.append(result_string)
```

Comment: You can add `assert dictionary["label"] in "glass cardboard trash metal paper".split()` if you want to check that the label is value is correct, and get an error if it isn't.

Comment: If you do not want commas between the values in the bbox, use `print("([{}], 0)".format(" ".join(str(d[key]) for key in "left top width height".split())))`

Comment: So I managed to get this to work for my use case tweaking your code a bit but since .split only does it for the first instance of the json object the pictures that I have with multiple annotations don't get properly converted. e.g. [{"left":191,"top":70,"width":183,"height":311,"label":"glass"}, {"left":200,"top":60,"width":132,"height":318,"label":"glass"}]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each row of your `bbox` column contains a `dictionary` inside of a `list`. I've tried to replicate your problem as follows. **Edit:** Clarifying that the below solution assumes that what you're referring to as a "JSON object" is represented as a `list` containing a single dictionary, which is what it appears to be per your example and screenshot.

```
# Create empty sample DataFrame with one row
df = pd.DataFrame([None],columns=['bbox'])

# Assign your sample item to the first row
df['bbox'][0] = [{"left":191,"top":70,"width":183,"height":311,"label":"glass"}]
```

Now, to simple *unpack* the row you can do:

```
df['bbox_unpacked'] = df['bbox'].map(lambda x: x[0].values())
```

Which will get you a new column with a `tuple` of 5 items.

If you want to go further and apply your labels, you'll likely want to create a dictionary to contain your labeling logic. Per the example you're given in the comments, I've done:

```
labels = {
    'cardboard': 1,
    'trash': 2,
    'glass': 3
}
```

This should get your your desired layout if you want a one-line solution without writing your own function.

```
df['bbox_unpacked'] = df['bbox'].map(lambda x: (list(x[0].values())[:4],labels.get(list(x[0].values())[-1])))
```

A more readable solution would be to define your own function using the `.apply()` method. **Edit:** Since it looks like your JSON object is being stored as a `str` inside your `DataFrame` rows, I added `json.loads(row)` to process the string first before retrieving the keys. You'll need to `import json` to run.

```
import json    

def unpack_bbox(row, labels):

    # load the string into a JSON object (in this
    # case a list of length one containing the dictionary;
    # index the list to its first item [0] and use the .values()
    # dictionary method to access the values only 

    keys = list(json.loads(row)[0].values())

    bbox_values = keys[:4]
    bbox_label = keys[-1]

    label_value = labels.get(bbox_label)

    return bbox_values, label_value

df['bbox_unpacked'] = df['bbox'].apply(unpack_bbox,args=(labels,))
```

Comment: For some reason I get multiple rows when I do BB_CSV['bbox'][0] - added an image to the post.

Comment: @cleme001 The `df['bbox'][0]` snippet was just to show how I assigned your sample list to a row of a sample `DataFrame` to replicate your issue. Have you tried `BB_CSV['bbox'].map(lambda x: x[0].values())` to unpack your rows?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the row it self is not a string but rather a numpyndarray so I'm getting this error.


BB_CSV['bbox'][0].values()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-57c5ca36959f> in <module>()
----> 1 BB_CSV['bbox'][0].values()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: Also if you look at the image I attached to the original post you'll see that when I even try to look at a single row I get back 5 different things not just the value of the row.

Comment: @cleme001 Does your DataFrame have duplicate values in it's index? Can you try `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False)` and try it again?

Comment: So resetting the index helped and now I only get one value but the .values() function still does not work as the dtype is still an object. '[{"left":71,"top":58,"width":439,"height":282,"label":"trash"}]'

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @cleme001 Added another edit to take care of case where your `DataFrame` is storing your JSON object as a `str`, which is what I think is happening per your last comment. Please try out the function approach (where I define `unpack_bbox(row, labels)`).

Comment: Ok so I actually got it working with the other guys' method but not able to add the tuple to another column 

for index, row in BB_CSV.iterrows():
    li = json.loads(BB_CSV['bbox'][0])
    d = dictionary = li[0]
    label = [d[key] for key in "label".split()]
    print(result)
    BB_CSV['bbox_2'] = (np.array([d[key] for key in "left top width height".split()]), cats[label[0]])